# Opened a source dir as Gradle project with IntelliJ but it's a maven project

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a java source folder with a `build.gradle` and `pom.xml`.

I use the `idea` bash script to open that folder with IntelliJ IDEA and IDEA imports the project as a gradle projecte, but the `build.gradle` is used for other tasks and it's not a gradle project.

It's a maven porject with a `pom.xml`.

How can I reimport the project as a maven project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and search for maven and select the `Reimport all Maven Projects` action.

[image]

After executing that action, your project will see the maven side bar icon and the project will be known as maven project.